# Encoding and decoding ruby symbols

Tags: ruby, json

I discovered this behavior of multi_json ruby gem:

```
2.1.0 :001 > require 'multi_json'
 => true
2.1.0 :002 > sym = :symbol
 => :symbol
2.1.0 :003 > sym.class
 => Symbol
2.1.0 :004 > res = MultiJson.load MultiJson.dump(sym)
 => "symbol"
2.1.0 :005 > res.class
 => String
```

Is this an appropriate way to store ruby symbols? Does JSON provide some way to distinguish `:symbol` from `"string"`?

Comment: Valid values in JSON are string, number, object, array, boolean and null. Other types must be converted, that's why symbols are stored as strings.

Answer (score 2):

Nope is the simple answer. Most of the time it only really matters for hashes and there's a cheat on hashes, `symbolize_keys!`.  Bottom line is that JSON does not understand symbols, just strings.

Since you are using MultiJson, you can also ask MultiJson to do this for you...

```
MultiJson.load('{"abc":"def"}', :symbolize_keys => true)
```

Comment: So the only way is to symbolize keys manually? Got it, thanks!

Comment: You can use a http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess - but that requires you controlling the hash creation which I don't think you can do using MultiJson easily. So if you feel like digging into MultiJson maybe you can make it happen.

Comment: Turns out I lied, it's already built in: `MultiJson.load('{"abc":"def"}', :symbolize_keys => true)`

Comment: I actually thought about uniquely definition of key types after dump load cycle. But since it can be merge into one (`{ :abc => "abc", "abc" => "def" } => {"abc"=>"def"}`), I see, its better to have some kind of rule for this.